# How should answers containing pure gibberish be flagged?

Tags: discussion

As an answer to the question [Does Louis Vuitton burn all their unsold bags?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/does-louis-vuitton-burn-all-their-unsold-bags/11093#comment45312_11093) someone has posted an answer saying

> No!These are sold as testicle holders at the open air market on Barsoom as they offer shelter from the brutal Martian climate for those delicate morsels.

It's obviously a trolling attempt and not offensive, and although in my opinion it's spam in its normal, everyday definition, it doesn't contain any advertising material so it doesn't fall under the site's definition of spam. How should such answers be flagged?

(I'm quoting the answer because I hope that it'll be deleted and then no trace of it will be left)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flagging as "not an answer" or "very low quality" is enough. 10k users can additionally vote to delete the post.

I destroyed the account of that user, removing all of his joke posts. In such cases where a user is posting multiple abusive posts, we moderators have tools that can deal with this very quickly. We don't need to act on each post, we can just nuke the entire account and all associated content. So it doesn't really matter what kind of flag you use, you only need to get our attention.

Spam flags can be used for [posts that are abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115629/151385), but this is not widely-known.